# Where is the logical error in this C program?

Tags: c, argv, argc

This is a simple program: pass user input via the main function in order to compute the range of a series of integers. However, the program is defaulting to the usage function. In other words, it does not seem to accept input from the command line.

The program executes, but somewhere along the way it reaches a condition where the usage message is printed to the terminal.

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int range(int a[], int *n, int *rng){
  //Declarations
  int i; //Dummy variable
  int min;
  int max;

  //Validate input
  if(!a || !n || !rng || *n <= 0) return -1;

  //Main execution
  min = a[0];
  max = a[0];

  for(i=0; i<*n; i++){
         if(a[i]<min)
                     min = a[i];
         if(a[i]>max)
                     max = a[i];  
  }
  *rng = max-min;
  return 0;
 }

void printUsage() {
   printf("\nUsage:[-s <series of at least two integers>] [-h help].");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
//Declarations
int setInt[100];
int i; //Dummy index
int n; //Temp variable
int err;
int rng;


//Run some tests to determine validity of input
for(i=0; i<argc; i++){

         //Is there at least some user input?
         if(argc == 1){ 
                 printUsage();
                 return -1;
         }
         //Determine if the user requested usage
         if(strcmp("-h", argv[i]) == 0){
                              printUsage();
                              return -1; //TRY REMOVING LATER TO SEE IF PROGRAM CAN KEPP RUNNING
         }
         //Determine if the user entered some data
         else if(strcmp("-s", argv[i]) == 0){
                              //There must be at least TWO arguments after this call
                              if((i+1) == argc || (i+2) == argc){
                                     printUsage();
                                     return -1;
                              }

                              //Start another loop to fill an array of values the user entered
                              //Reuse i, but start at three to grap the first supposed integer
                              for(i=3; i < argc; i++){
                                       err = sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &n);
                                       if(err == 0) {//The input wasn't an integer
                                              printUsage();
                                              return -1;
                                       }
                                       else {
                                            assert(err == 1);
                                            setInt[i-3] = n; //Store the variable in an array
                                       }                 
                              }


              }

         else{//unknown input
                        printUsage();
                        return -1;
         }
//For bracket
}

//Call the function

printf("The range of values entered is %d.", rng);
range(setInt, &argc, &rng);
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
//Main bracket
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code line by line, and you will see *exactly* when, where and why.

Comment: Oh, and don't return `-1` from `main`. Instead just return just `1` (or return `EXIT_FAILURE` from `<stdlib.h>`).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why - at least in my course they prefer -1?

Comment: I hope you are passing the numbers ALONG when you run the main program i.e. on the same line as you type the exe and NOT after the program starts executing?

Comment: @Mlagma, you'd have to ask them directly :) `EXIT_FAILURE` is the only thing that is guaranteed to work portable on all platforms.

Comment: Yes, I am - I'm using a linux terminal. That would be, ./range -s ...

Comment: Because, depending on platform, the return value is used by other parts of the system, and there it might be a bit-field where only the the low eight bits are supposed to be the returned value. If you return `-1` then *all* the bits of that bit-field are set and that may confuse the other systems. Since you are on a Linux system, you might read about the [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) system call which have more details about that.

Comment: Regarding your problem, `argv[0]` will *never* be equal to `"-h"` or `"-s"`. Oh, and that check for `argc == 1` should be before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you don't increment i before looking for -s
change the line

```
     else if(strcmp("-s", argv[i]) == 0){ //i is still zero, so argv[i] is the command entered
```

to

```
     else if(strcmp("-s", argv[++i]) == 0){
```

(add ++ before the i) and it won't print usage.

Comment: You're on the right track, but not quite there. Instead of doing `++i` *there*, the loop should start with `i = 1`.

Comment: That's what I wound up implementing. After using gdb, I saw that issue.